# Foreach a specific key from array

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I have an array with 2 same keys i want to foreach out if possible. The currently code looks like:

```
$arrayName = array(
    1 => array('detail' => 'detail1' , 'detail' => 'detail2')
);

foreach ($arrayName[1] as $key['detail'] => $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your keys are overwriting themselves.  You may want to approach the solution like this:

```
$arrayName = array(
    array('name' => 'detail' , 'value' => 'detail1'),
    array('name' => 'detail' , 'value' => 'detail2')
);

foreach ($arrayName as $i) {
    echo $i['value'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out to understand how to do it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have identical keys for an array.. The final key overwrites the first one. (in your case)

From the [**PHP Docs**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)..

> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only
> the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

#### A dynamic way of doing this..

```
<?php
$new_arr = array();
foreach(range(1,5) as $v)
{
    $new_arr['detail'.$v]='detail'.$v;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [detail1] => detail1
    [detail2] => detail2
    [detail3] => detail3
    [detail4] => detail4
    [detail5] => detail5
)
```

Comment: Why not different keys ? :) `detail1` and `detail2` ?

Comment: I building an application and want to keep it easy :)

Comment: Then create an array of arrays and keep the key same for the sub arrays